# Ngrx Effects not listening to actions

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-effects

I want to use ngrx/efffects and ngrx/store in my angular app(v7). I am eveything configured in my app as suggested in [ngrx documentation](https://ngrx.io/guide/store/reducers). On dispatching action in AppComponent, reducer is working as expected but looks like **effects is not listening to any action**.

Testing:

Check the console, after doing `ng serve -o`. Everything is logged as expected, except the one in effects.

Please suggest where did I go wrong.

[Github Repo](https://github.com/raj2033/angular-project-structure)

**Effects**

```js
@Injectable()
export class AppEffects {
  constructor(
    private actions$: Actions,
    private myService: MyserviceService
  ) {}

  myAction$ = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType<fromActions.GetItems>(MyActionTypes.GET_ITEMS),
    switchMap(action => {
      console.log('i am in effects', action);
      return this.myService.getItems().pipe(
        map(data => new fromActions.GetItemsSuccess(data)),
        catchError(err => of(new fromActions.GetItemsSuccess(err)))
      );
    })
  );
}
```

**Configured effects in AppModule**

```js
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    StoreModule.forRoot(reducers, { metaReducers }),
    EffectsModule.forRoot([AppEffects])
  ],
})
```

Dispatching action in AppComponent

```js
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private store: Store<State>) {
    console.log('in component');
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log('dispatched action in AppComponent');
    this.store.dispatch(new fromAction.GetItems());
  }
}
```

Comment: Please post some relevant sections of the code in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing [`@Effect()`](https://ngrx.io/api/effects/Effect) decorator without which those observables won't get registered as store's side effects.

```
import { Effect, Actions, ofType } from '@ngrx/effects';

//....

@Injectable()
export class AppEffects {
 //  ....

  @Effect()
  myAction$ = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType<fromActions.GetItems>(MyActionTypes.GET_ITEMS),
    switchMap(action => {
      console.log('i am in effects', action);
      return this.myService.getItems().pipe(
        map(data => new fromActions.GetItemsSuccess(data)),
        catchError(err => of(new fromActions.GetItemsSuccess(err)))
      );
    })
  );
}
```

Comment: can you sugget, if there is any best practise to organize angular project structure.?